# Lost the ability to fold code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have lost the ability to fold my code in Eclipse (Helios).

I have always used <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>/</kbd> but now it's not doing anything in one particular project and also all the "+" signs have vanished from the left bar.

Can anyone tell me what I have done?
In another project it's fine, but the one I'm currently working on I can't and it's so frustrating!

Comment: Do you open files with correct editor? Right-click on the file and try selecting different editor in the Open with menu.

Comment: I'm opening them with the java editor as I assume it always has? There doesn't appear to another relevant editor!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Folding is configured under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor ->Folding

The Preferences window has a search box - very useful to find even the most obscure options.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It was disabled! I have no idea how I managed to do that as I've never been in that option!

Comment: Just to note, the answer above works only for Java settings. If you're working with C++, or some other language, use the same steps as above but replace Java with your language name. Or better yet, type 'Folding' in the Preferences search bar, and you will see the folding settings for all available languages.

Comment: Apparently `ctrl + NUMPAD-/` is the default key binding to disable folding. This is a horrible choice when `ctrl + shift + NUMPAD-/` is the key binding to fold all code. Very easy to miss the shift and disable folding.

Comment: It was disabled for me, too. Without any reasons. The second time. Really annoying.

Comment: What causes code-folding to be turned off in the first place? 

Mine stopped working but can't trace back to root cause, hadn't been fiddling with anything else in config or preferences beforehand.

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1:**

`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor ->Folding`

**Method 2**

`ctrl + NUMPAD-/`

**Method 3**

Right-click where line-numbers are (should be). Go to Folding -> Enable Folding.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the checkbox "Enable Folding" under Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Folding

By default, it would be Ctrl + Shift + Numpad_Divide but it can be changed from 
Windows -> Preference -> General -> Keys (type collapse in the search box and edit).

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same situation, after running Eclipse for a few days. I believe there's a bug in Eclipse.  Just close the file and reopen it, it'll work again. Or, for the worst case, restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same issue but none of the advice here worked as my root cause was different. So I feel obligated to share it to make this thread complete:

I use Atollic TrueSTUDIO for STM32 (v. 9.3.0), which is a flavor of Eclipse for STM32 MCUs. I hope this applies to vanilla Eclipse as well.

For me, the solution was to right click the project in the 'Project explorer', then Index -> Freshen All Files.